# Struggling with REST and Larman's (RCP?) system operations

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, methodology

In Craig Larman's book [Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062), a use case is converted to a System Sequence Diagram (SSD) which contains system operations. It's a way of doing high-level design first, that's easily traceable to the requirements (use case), and later refining it by detailing the system operations at the domain level via OO design principles.

I'm trying to understand this methodology using RESTful services. The trouble spots seem to be with **resources** and the **stateless operations**.

Here's a sample from the book, an SSD with four system operations:

[image: Example of a SSD - System Sequence Diagram]

An SSD is also an abstraction of the presentation layer (on the left) and the domain layer (on the right). The domain layer might also include the application and or business logic.

In Larman's approach, a system operation (e.g., `makeNewSale()`) should be handled by a [GRASP Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Controller) which is a <del>domain</del> non-presentation-layer object that handles the system operation.

Now, let's say we're trying to use RESTful services in this approach:

- The **Uniform Interface** constraint of REST is part of the presentation layer. For example, one can configure the *route* that a POST operation on a resource takes, allowing it to eventually call some operation of an object in the Domain layer. This [Byte Rot blog by Aliostad](http://byterot.blogspot.ca/2013/10/api-layer-and-its-responsibilities-rest-viewpoint-webapi-csds-aspnetwebapi.html) explains very well the details of traditional layer architectures and REST.

  - In Larman's example, the Cashier clicks somewhere in the GUI to invoke a `http://...com/sales - POST request` and eventually a GRASP Controller receives `makeNewSale()`. The REST part `http://...com/sales - POST request` creates a new resource for the sale e.g., `001` and also `makeNewSale()` is sent to a GRASP controller object.
    [image: Sequence diagram showing layers]
- Session Controllers (mentioned in the GRASP Controller pattern) don't exist on the System, since REST operations are stateless on the server. This implies that system operations might actually need more arguments to pass state information to the server, and that isn't obvious from the use case. For example, `makeNewSale()` probably needs to receive and process an authentication token as an argument, since `:System` has no session information. I found a related question and answers here at [RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319530/1168342)

So, assuming my understanding up to now is right, my questions are:

1. Does the **Uniform Interface** constraint of REST respect loose coupling of presentation/domain layer separation? At first, it seems to be a detail of the presentation layer (like an `actionPerformed()` method in Java Swing). But the part that bothers me is that `http://...com/sales` ties right into a `Sale` (which is a domain) object.
   Another way of putting it: by creating REST resources and REST verbs accessing them via a Uniform Interface, isn't application/business logic being put into to the presentation layer? Larman's SSD approach is about layers and he explicitly states that application logic should not go in the presentation layer. For example, a POST to `http://...com/sales` creates a new `sales/001` resource and also sends `makeNewSale()`. The first part seems like business logic. The fact that my REST resource names follow many of my Domain object names seems like my Presentation layer is (more) coupled to my Domain layer, than if I were using Swing and only called `makeNewSale()` from an `actionPerformed()` on a `JButton`.
2. Larman's SSD concept is oriented towards the RCP model (with state in the server), but can an SSD be made to easily jibe with a REST philosophy? For example, `endSale()` exists to break the system out of a loop of `enterItem()` calls. Later in the book, Larman even presents a state diagram about this:
   [image: State diagram for DSS]
   I read about [How to manage state in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641901/how-to-manage-state-in-rest) and it seems one has to take care with passing state on each system operation if needed (as in the authentication token example above), or the "state" is actually encapsulated in the resources. I thought about it, and with REST, `endSale()` could probably be removed entirely.

I used a concrete example here, so that the answers can also be concrete.

Comment: I just watched [Jim Webber's talk at YOW 2011](https://yow.eventer.com/events/1004/talks/1047) and heard him discuss *side effects* on resources. He mentions *infinite numbers* of resources, which I think speaks to using them as abstractions rather than direct access to domain objects. In some cases it's OK to have them directly linked; in others it is not (hence the side effect). A *side effect* on a resource could just be a system operation in Larman's method.

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35708211/1168342 is very related. I should have googled DDD and REST sooner.

Comment: Another thing that helps (to transition) is knowing that REST is a kind of spectrum (you don't have to go all the way, and Larman's RPI is like Level 0): https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to address your questions, but keep in mind that this is a very much debatable topic..

1. The REST Uniform Interface does respect the separation of concerns between presentation and business logic. The separation is about the presentation layer not knowing details about the implementation of the business logic and vice-versa, but there is no point in hiding what can be done with a domain entity (i.e. the services that are available for a resource). What you want to hide is **how** the actions are executed.
2. The REST's HATEOAS principle dictates that the representation of a resource (the instance of a domain entity) should encapsulate the state of the client/server interaction, so the services should return that state to the client one way or another. This, and the use of hypermedia (i.e. links to available services - representing actions that can be done on a resource, given its state) should map quite easily to the state diagram you posted.

Let's continue with your example :

let's say that there is a service `newSale` returning a `Sale` object. This service must be invoked using the `POST` method. in the `Sale`'s `hypermedia` section there are 2 links, one to the `addItem` service (which is also a `POST` and accepts an updated version of the `Sale` object, returning it after it has been saved), and one to the `endSale` service (also a `POST`), which saves the `Sale` and marks it as 'complete'. This last service does not return any resource representation, just the http response OK if the object is succesfully saved.

Comment: Your example for evolving state is convincing. I was missing the point about posts evolving resources and their representations. As for point 1, in mvc, the views are aware of model objects. The part I find troubling is the mapping of resources and verbs that is dependent on the operations on domain objects. There's got to be code to sync the resource representation with the domain object's state. It *feels* like a violation of information hiding.