# Architecture of asp.net web api doing calculations with input from a POST request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I am making a pretty complex "calculator" as a web API. So that I can POST the input to the ASP.NET Web API, and then it returns the appropriate answers/reports.

I am just wondering how the architecture of this should be. I now have an api controller which takes the input, and binds it to a Input model, which stores all the input.

Where should the calculations be done? In the same model?
Or should I make a Calculation model which contains all the business logic, and then I call the appropriate methods and such from the api controller?

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a pretty complex "calculator" ...
>   Where should the calculations be done?

IIUC, that means there are some complex business rules needs to be designed. A good way to address complex models is to follow the [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (DDD) practices. That has nothing in common with REST.

> should I make a Calculation model which contains all the business logic, and then I call the appropriate methods and such from the api controller?

As soon as you implement the business logic in the Domain layer, you may expose that to (web) clients using [RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700344/rest-api-and-ddd).