# Caching API user credentials

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code running on every HTTP request:

```
if ($request->header('Authorization')) {
    $token = $request->header('Authorization');
    $user = User::where('api_token', $token)->whereRaw("`api_token_expires` >= CURDATE()")->active()->first();
    if ($user) {
        $GLOBALS['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $GLOBALS['is_admin'] = $user->admin;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm hitting the database for every request looking for a valid API token.

What's a more efficient - but safe, best practice - way of handling this? Should I be looking at MySQL caching? Redis or something else?

EDIT: I'm not using sessions, this is a stateless API.

Comment: Best possible way is to use redis  for faster access. Rest everything is fine. It depends upon the hits you will be receiving if traffic is less mysql is okay

Answer (score 0):

You can make api-users authorize first and respond with a session token.

Then they can use this session token for each next request.

You can store these sessions in the $_SESSION variable, on disk in a file or on a fast database like Redis.

To do this securely I would remove old sessions automatically, check the session token against it's origin IP, and force https for the api.

Comment: I'm not using sessions at all though - this is actually Lumen and it's a stateless API.

Comment: ah, then you might want to look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641901/how-to-manage-state-in-rest